# Frequency of a sequential circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, logic-gates, timing-analysis

I'm reading the book *Digital Design and Computer Architecture*. I came across this exercise:

[image]

From what I've learned so far, the frequency of a circuit is the reciprocal of the clock period. Since we have 3 inverters in a loop, I suppose the total time is \$N\times t_{pd}\$, therefore the oscillator should operate at a frequency between \$\frac{1}{N\times t_{pd}}\$ and \$\frac{1}{N\times t_{cd}}\$.

But instead the solution states that it operates at a frequency between \$\frac{1}{2\times N\times t_{pd}}\$ and \$\frac{1}{2\times N\times t_{cd}}\$. Where does the 2 come from?

Comment: It inverts and then it inverts, again, in order to create a complete cycle, perhaps? ;) Think of the single inverter case.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now.

Comment: Good. It's not hard. You just need to take a moment's time and walk yourself through an entire cycle.

Comment: I love this site by the way :D Got instant and clear answers that really helped me. Thank you guys!

Comment: for your unfriendly closed Q. https://tinyurl.com/y37enj9f

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Wow that is perfect! :D It's much more clear now how the FSM operates. They advised me to use logisim-evolution before closing the question, and after reading the tutorial I was able to sketch something similar to what you did here, so not all was lost! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The times \$N\cdot t_{pd}\$ and \$N\cdot t_{cd}\$ represent the max and min times needed for a single transition to make its way around the ring of N oscillators. However, one cycle requires two transitions to make it around the ring - one that brings the output high, and the second which brings the output low.

Comment: If I understand this right, if we start with 0 as input we get (0->1->0->1->0->1->0...). Thus we need to complete two transitions to get a low and a high.